# Separate two website in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

There are two domains, two websites and two stores but one magento (1.9) and one database.
e.g. 
Site1 is on domain 1 and site 2 is on domain 2 but magento is one and both site have same database.

What i want, separate the magento and both database?Please tell me how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take some time to follow the [Stack Overflow tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Also provide us the relevant code you wrote for your question (You can also read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Answer (score 0):

Since you have one root folder(magento).Point both domains to this root folder(your magento folder);

Then goto `index.php` and add this code: before `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);`

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'example.com':
    case 'www.example.com':
        $mageRunCode = 'base';
        $mageRunType = 'website';
    break;
    case 'example2.com':
    case 'www.example2.com':

        $mageRunCode = 'example2';
        $mageRunType = 'website'; 
    break;
}
```

mageRunCode wiil be your website code.Change it accordingly.

goto `system->configuration`
there you might need to update the web and design tabs..
change the `Current Configuration Scope:` and update values from web and design tabs to appropriate values.

Refer this link for more info:https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/30/How-To-Setup-Magento-With-Multiple-Stores-And-Domains